# KML format writeFeatures defaultStyle

Tags: openlayers

I am having trouble understanding `defaultStyle` when using ol.format.KML writeFeatures(). The features that I am writing out do not have individual styles so I want to apply the layer style to the KML features. I tried this:

```
var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures(); // these do not have styles
var layerStyle = vectorLayer.getStyleFunction()(features[0], map.getView().getResolution());
var kmlFormat = new ol.format.KML({
  defaultStyle: layerStyle
})

var kml = kmlFormat.writeFeatures(features, {
  featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()  // source coord sys
});
console.log(kml);
```

But the kml has no styling. If I copy the layer's style to each feature:

```
features.forEach(function(feature) {
  feature.setStyle(layerStyle);
});
```

Then the kml has styling, even if I remove `{defaultStyle: layerStyle}`. But I would prefer not to copy the style from the layer into each individual feature. Ideally I would like the kml to have the layer's style for features that do not have their own style and use the feature's style for ones that do have their own style.

So what does `defaultStyle` do and when would it be used?

[OpenLayers docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.KML.html)

Maybe `defaultStyle` applies only to reading KML, not writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KML is different than other feature formats. It was designed to carry features with styles. So when writing KML, only styles that are associated with features end up in the KML. This is independent from the `defaultStyle` setting, which only configures the style to use for `readFeatures` when no style is configured for a feature.